# how can i use res.render for ejs multiple times?

Tags: node.js, express, render, ejs

I'm trying to call res.render twice in my nodeJS application but I keep getting an error, when I do so. does anyone know how I could call res.render twice in my app, without switching the file? or including it in all one res.render or changing the director?

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("index", {
        data: "Hello, guys",
    });
    res.render("index", {
        name: "Hello, again",
    });
});

app.listen(10022, function () {
    console.log("server is up");
});
```

I know the above code will not work. I would like to know how i can send data, and name at different times during the code.

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't make a lot of sense. You should get an error as your handler tries to send response headers twice which is wrong. What on earth are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I know the above won't work. I'm just seeing how i can send data and name, at different times during the code.

Comment: This is not how HTTP works. You should send 2 HTTP requests for getting 2 different responses.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same issue because I had multiple asynchronous http calls happening as part of processing the first json response I got from my server and I had to wait for all of them to complete before rendering the response. The way I addressed this is that I kept a counter on how many http request I had to make and then call res.render after that. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are going to do. However if you just want to render 'index.ejs' file with 'data' and 'name', you can simply put together like below.

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("index", {
        data: "Hello, guys",
        name: "Hello, again"
    });
});
```